# Count subarrays divisible by K

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a sequence of n positive integers we need to count consecutive sub-sequences whose sum is divisible by k.

Constraints : N is up to 10^6 and each element up to 10^9 and K is up to 100

EXAMPLE : Let N=5 and K=3 and array be 1 2 3 4 1

Here answer is 4

Explanation : there exists, 4 sub-sequences whose sum is divisible by 3, they are

```
3
1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

My Attempt :

```
long long int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    long long int sum=0;
    for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[j];
        if(sum%k==0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

But obviously its poor approach. Can their be better approach for this question? Please help.

Complete Question: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w6/challenges/consecutive-subsequences

Comment: Do you want sub-sequences or subarrays

Comment: @AyushJain Consecutive Subsequences,As mentioned

Comment: @Ben Yeah consecutive ones

Comment: Suppose your array is [1,4,3,2,1], then what output do you expect. Can you tell?

Comment: This hints at dynamic programming, but I'll need to think about it to formulate it

Comment: Your code will not count all such subsequences. It is easy to see, if all numbers together without second one are divided by K, you will never try to sum 1 and 3 elements without 2 element.

Comment: Yeah subsequence will be generated using DP. Is this homework?

Comment: @AyushJain With what K?

Comment: @AyushJain No..PLeas its not any homework

Comment: @Arkady I need consecutive subsequences

Comment: @AyushJain here answer is 4 for ur test case

Comment: I'm putting this here to seed thoughts, I know its bad: Dynamic programming: Rem[i,j] = remainder of subsequence A[i]...A[j], Rem[i,i]=A[i]%k,Rem[i,j]=(Rem[i,j-1]+(A[j]%k)) % k = (Rem[i,j-i]+Rem[j,j])%k.

Comment: you can simplify your calculations if you take %K of all input numbers and will work with rests. So, you will work with numbers below 100, that will help you to avoid overflow.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Please provide proper answer with explanation

Comment: do you need consecutive sub-sequences or sub-sequences? Because `1 2 3 ` and `2 3 4` are sub-sequences, but they're not consecutive.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore By consecutive i mean the elements of subsequence should be continous

Comment: @user3786422 It isn't an answer, cuz I end up with the same complexity for all operations but take up O(n^2) space on top of it.

Comment: I got a slower solution that is O(NK) but it is easier to understand, if you want I can post it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a fast O(n + k) solution:

1)Lets compute prefix sums pref[i](for 0 <= i < n).

2)Now we can compute count[i] - the number of prefixes with sum i modulo k(0 <= i < k).
This can be done by iterating over all the prefixes and making count[pref[i] % k]++.
Initially, count[0] = 1(an empty prefix has sum 0) and 0 for i != 0.

3)The answer is sum count[i] * (count[i] - 1) / 2 for all i.

4)It is better to compute prefix sums modulo k to avoid overflow.

Why does it work? Let's take a closer a look at a subarray divisible by k. Let's say that it starts in L position and ends in R position. It is divisible by k if and only if pref[L - 1] == pref[R] (modulo k) because their differnce is zero modulo k(by definition of divisibility). So for each fixed modulo, we can pick any two prefixes with this prefix sum modulo k(and there are exactly count[i] * (count[i] - 1) / 2 ways to do it).

Here is my code:

```
long long get_count(const vector<int>& vec, int k) {
  //Initialize count array.
  vector<int> cnt_mod(k, 0);
  cnt_mod[0] = 1;
  int pref_sum = 0;
  //Iterate over the input sequence.
  for (int elem : vec) {
    pref_sum += elem;
    pref_sum %= k;
    cnt_mod[pref_sum]++;
  }
  //Compute the answer.
  long long res = 0;
  for (int mod = 0; mod < k; mod++)
    res += (long long)cnt_mod[mod] * (cnt_mod[mod] - 1) / 2;
  return res;
}
```

Comment: why count[pref[i] % k]++.?

Comment: By defenition of count[i] - the number of prefixes with sum i modulo k.

Comment: Nice solution -- I think you mean count[i] * (count[i] - 1) / 2 in step 3?

Comment: Wow, please, clarify your idea.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about my solition? What part to clarify?

Comment: Not saying it doesn't work, can you dumb it down for us slow people?

Comment: Hrm...I must be confused, can you run it on the example? A={1,2,3,4,1}, pref={1,3,6,10,11}, perf%3={1,0,0,1,2},count={2,2,1}, sum count[i]*(count[i]-1)/2=1+1+0=2 != 4.

Comment: This did not seem to work, but perhaps it needs clarification from the author: http://ideone.com/aHh7st

Comment: @user2040251 Yeah Please explain by some example or psuedocode

Comment: count[0] is initially one for an empty prefix. count={3,2,1} and the sum is 4.

Comment: For 1 2 3 4 1 0 it gives (3,2,2) and sum 5, but there is still 4

Comment: It should give 5. A subarray which consist of only one element 0 is also divisible.

Comment: Very Nice!, Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

That have to make your calculations easier:

```
//Now we will move all numbers to [0..K-1]
long long int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i]%K;
}

//Now we will calculate cout of all shortest subsequences.
long long int sum=0; 
int first(0); 
std::vector<int> beg;
std::vector<int> end;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (arr[i] == 0)
    {
        count++; 
        continue;
    }
    sum += arr[i];
    if (sum == K)
    {
        beg.push_back(first);
        end.push_back(i);
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        while (sum > K)
        {
            sum -= arr[first];
            first++;     
        }
        if (sum == K)
        {
            beg.push_back(first);
            end.push_back(i);
            count++;
        }
    }        
}

//this way we found all short subsequences. And we need to calculate all subsequences that consist of some short subsequencies.
int party(0);
for (int i = 0; i < beg.size() - 1; ++i)
{
    if (end[i] == beg[i+1])
    {
        count += party + 1;
        party++;
    }
    else
    {
        party = 0;
    } 
}
```

So, with max array size = 10^6 and max size of rest = 99, you will not have overflow even if you will need to summ all numbers in simple int32.

And time you will spend will be around O(n+n)

Comment: Your solution is still `O(N^2)`

Comment: @Ben nope, note the inner loop uses `arr`.

Comment: It's just idea to optimize overflow problem. I didn't find way to have less n^n yet.

Comment: A DP algorithm exists, but this suggestion is better suited as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, maybe you are right. But while now I doubt algorithm faster then n*n exists. Still, will think about it tomorrow. Interesting task.